# Запретить новичкам добавлять какую-нибудь метку до набора некоего количества баллов

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Я постоянно просматриваю вопросы на SO по тэгу [Unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)

И последним временем на него напали сотни аккаунтов-однодневок с глупыми и примитивными вопросами. Эти вопросы бесполезны для ресурса по своей сути практически все. Они же остаются без ответа из-за того, что ни у кого нету ни малейшего желания разбираться с человеком который хочет влезть в гейм-девелопмент, но не хочет разбираться с азами программирования....

Я вижу как решение или добавить блокировку на тэг новичкам.. Хотя бы до баллов 50... **Или выдавать какое-то предупреждение что нужно разбираться сначала с Шарпом прежде чем лезть в юнити... Или я не знаю что - ваши идеи.**

Они просто загадили весь интересный тэг и возвращаться назад к просмотру вопросов буквально хочется меньше и меньше.

Более того, у более опытных пользователей начинается упрежденно плохое отношение к вопросам от новичков. Например как у Ярослава: [Тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1239191/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment2175156_1239191). Вопрос был хоть и от новичка, но весьма неплохим и  полезным для ресурса(он, даже, сумел собрать 9 плюсов за пару дней после простой правки заголовка). Но Ярослав просто не рассмотрел потенциал вопроса.

Такие наплывы "абсолютных нулей" в тэг, в котором не место полным нулям в программировании, буквально убивает все ru.SO unity комьюнити.

**Пожалуста, не концентрируйте внимание на варианте "запрет на тег" - я спросил и про другие варианты. И предложил в том числе плашку-предупреждение что с юнити начинать не стоит.**

Comment: Эти вопросы не являются дубликатами. Вопрос про другое.

Comment: Если заменить в твоем вопросе _ruSo Unity_ на просто _ruSo_ - получится как раз вопрос дубликат.

Comment: @Grundy что бы лезть в что-то сложное нужно получить базовые знания. Пытаясь изучать высшую математику нужно сначала освоится в простой математике. Мой вопрос не про то что нельзя изучать юнити или что юнити только для высших слоев общества программистов. Я ничего не писал про тег шарпа и достаточно часто отвечаю там на вопросы от новичков по нему. Дети должны учится. Если ты видишь вопросы одинаковыми, перечитай пожалуста. Вопрос касается больше того, что новички не осознают во что лезут. А от этого как следствие страдает ресурс. Сколько из вопросов задаются там с количеством балов выше 50?

Comment: Просто тег "юнити" начинает превращаться в консультирование совсем не по вопросам юнити.

Comment: Ты можешь редактировать метки вопроса, если вопрос относится не у unity, а другим областям.

Comment: _Такие наплывы "абсолютных нулей" в тэг, в котором не место полным нулям в программировании, буквально убивает все ru.SO unity комьюнити._ - собственно это тезис из вопроса дубликата, только суженый до одной метки.

Comment: @Grundy метки в которой нужно иметь базу программирования перед тем как туда лезть. Я же не говорю не изучать программирование. Просто все должно изучаться по порядку усложнения. Попробуй обьяснить первокласснику вопрос по тригонометрии - у тебя не получится. Это не говорит что тригонометрия для избранных, так ведь? Но понятия предшествующие ей нужно понимать что бы ее начинать обьяснять.

Comment: Если ты не можешь что-то объяснить пятилетнему ребенку, скорее  всего ты и сам этого не знаешь :)

Comment: Повторюсь: если ты считаешь, что вопрос относится не к unity, достаточно просто добавить соответствующие метки и убрать лишние. Если вопрос относится к unity - тогда непонятно в чем проблема.

Comment: @Grundy только для этого прийдется обьяснять всю предшествующую этой теме информацию. То есть займет это столько времени, что реально бессмысленно вкладываться если это не твой личный ребенок. А на ruSO в теге юнити я своих детей не видел)))

Comment: Для чего? Удаления метки и закрытия как дубликат?

Comment: @Andrew, в рамках текущей структуры сайта (SO) такие вопросы (относится и к др. меткам) не имеют решения. Для их решения можно было бы разделить сайт на 2 части -- песочницу (для новичков) и основную часть. И т.п.

Comment: Я против такого запрета. Новичок может задать хороший вопрос, а т. к. метку он не может поставить, то этот вопрос не увидят те, кто подписан на эту метку. И вопрос останется без ответа.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - снова таки - это один из предложенных вариантов проблемы. Я там же предложил и плашку что изучать сходу юнити нежелательно как второй вариант решения проблемы.

Comment: Вопрос задает новичок, но отвечать на него будут не только новички. У многих кто занимается ответами настроены уведомления и фильтры по меткам и они просматривают вопросы переходя по своим фильтрам. Ваше пожелаение отбирает инструмент у экспертов, который помогает быстро увидеть вопрос и дать на него ответ новичку.

Comment: @Andrew а кто дал вам право решать что в какой-то теме не место новичкам? Давайте запретим детям изучать физику, потому что в этой науке не место полным нулям. Есть минуса, есть тревоги. Если вы так переживаете за чистоту своей любимой метки, так боритесь доступными инструментами, а не запретами. Легче запретить, чем ставить минуса, тревоги, писать авторам вопросов комментарии чтобы они стали лучше и умнее.

Answer (score 4):

## Не надо.

- Новичок *на ruSO* может быть профессионал и очень опытный человек по жизни. И даже наоборот наверно (за это не ручаюсь, не уверен, хотя чего только не бывает.). ⇒ не надо.
- Метки для всех. Все равно что запретить использовать само unity новичкам. ⇒ не надо
- На SE все равны. Все. Новички, не новички — no matter. Все. ⇒ не надо
- И в результате этого запрета просто будут использовать неправильные метки. ⇒ не надо.

> И последним временем на него напали сотни аккаунтов-однодневок с глупыми и примитивными вопросами. Эти вопросы бесполезны для рессурса по своей сути практически все. Они же остаются без ответа из-за того что ни у кого нету ни малейшего желания разбираться с человеком который хочет влезть в гейм-девелопмент, но не хочет разбираться с азами программирования....

Найс. Двойные стандарты. Может пусть новички учатся? Что же касается плохих вопросов — их можно закрывать и минусовать.

> Я вижу как решение или добавить блокировку на тэг новичкам.. Хотя бы до балов 50... Или выдавать какое-то предупреждение что нужно разбираться сначала с Шарпом прежде чем лезть в юнити... Или я не знаю что - ваши идеи.

- Это их дело.
- Это испортит поиск вопросов.

> Они просто загадили весь интересный тэг и возвращаться назад к просмотру вопросов буквально хочется меньше и меньше.

Ваше право читать или не читать вопросы по тегу. "Засрали"? Эх... Может пусть новички учатся?

> Более того, у более опытных пользователей начинается упрежденно плохое отношение к вопросам от новичков. Например как у Ярослава: Тыц. Вопрос был хоть и от новичка, но весьма неплохим и полезным для ресурса(он, даже, сумел собрать 9 плюсов). Но Ярослав просто не рассмотрел.

Есть флаги ;)

> Такие наплывы "абсолютных нулей" в тэг, в котором не место полным нулям в программировании, буквально убивает все ru.SO unity комьюнити.

Просто не согласен. И все.

Comment: я предложил не только запрет метки, но и плашку-предупреждение что начинать сначала нужно с базы программирования, а не с юнити. Это предложение никоим образом не ограничивает никаких пользователей и не дает никаких привилегий другим пользователям. Да и вообще спросил какие есть другие пути решения проблемы. А здесь ты сконцентрировался только на одной из идей которая тебе больше всего не понравилась.

Comment: @Andrew edited. Я часто начинаю с главной мысли, а потом расширяю правками. ;)

Comment: Я не против вопросов от новичков. Более того, я не раз отстаивал их вопросы от закрытия или нападок. Никаких двойных стандартов. Просто рано лезть в тригонометрию не зная основ математики. Так и с юнити - нужно начинать с основ программирования на C# перед тем как переходить к юнити. Слишком много побочных сложностей для изучения основ программирования этим путем.

Comment: @Andrew И какое это имеет отношение к ruSO?

Comment: Это была аллегория. проапдейтил комментарий.

Comment: @Andrew Да мне понятно было (кстати это сравнение). Я имею в виду ruSO никого не обязано настальжвать на истинный путь XD

Comment: аллегория это тоже сравнение)

Comment: @Andrew Не-а... Это не синонимы. Хотя похожие понятия.